# Dart polymer Google Picker

Tags: javascript, interop, dart, polymer, google-picker

I have two Dart projects that use the Google (docs) Picker API. One is 'raw' Dart and the other uses the Polymer framework.

I have a big issue where on the 'raw' Dart project works fine, but Polymer crashes Dartium when I call:

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS).setDeveloperKey(developerKey).setCallback(pickerCallback).setOrigin(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host).build();

// Add the view to the DOM
picker.setVisible(true);
```

It is actually the `picker.setVisible(true);` that causes Dartium to crash.

Can you think of why this would be? There are no errors thrown and it goes directly to "Aw, Snap!".

UPDATE:

This issues was fixed with the latest SDK release 0.8.10.3_r29803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the latest "package:google_oauth2_client/google_oauth2_browser.dart"; with the Picker API. Display issues were fixed in Version 1 of Dart